# Animate CAShapeLayer's path by transform.scale property

Tags: swift, cashapelayer, cgpath

I'm trying to animate scale of `CAShapeLayer` that has a circle path (playground compatible):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)))
view.backgroundColor = .white

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
animation.duration = 1
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.toValue = 1
animation.autoreverses = true
animation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude

let frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
let path = CGPath(ellipseIn: frame, transform: nil)

let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.frame = frame
layer.path = path
layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Here is the result:

[image]

The red circle is the figure that i trying to get animated with scale animation right in the center of its position and without any translation. This circle set as `CGPath` to `CAShapeLayer`.

The problem is obvious – my `CAShapeLayer` with blue background color animating as it expected, but the path – not.

Am i missed something or this is the way it works? Maybe this animation should be done in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, what you need is a bounds not frame.

```
let frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
```

should be:

```
let bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
let path = CGPath(ellipseIn: bounds, transform: nil)
```

Hope it is what you need.

Comment: ooh, so simple :) sometime it's really tricky to get things right about frame and bounds. thanks, man!